# sys/ucred.hが見つからない

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

getmntinfo関数を利用するプログラムを書きました。

> gcc o.c -o o 
>   o.c:5:22: fatal error: sys/ucred.h: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません

実際、自分の使っているubuntu16.04には`/usr/include/sys/ucred.h`ファイルはありませんでした。

`man getmntinfo`で確認しましたがマニュアルは発見できなかったそうです。
/のプロパティによるとファイルシステムの種類はext3/ext4だそうです。
標準で存在しないファイルなのですか？
他の関数を利用したほうがいいのですか？

Comment: `/usr/include/sys/ucred.h` ファイルは FreeBSD や Mac OS X にはあるかと思います。内容は `SCM_CREDENTIALS message` を格納する構造体(`ucred`)の宣言ですが、Linux の場合は `/usr/include/bits/socket.h` 内にあって、`#include <sys/socket.h>` とすればインクルードされます。なお、インクルードする前に `_GNU_SOURCE` を `define` しておく必要があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getmntinfo` は BSD 系の関数です。
[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) や HP-UX では `getmntent` を使うことになるのかな。
https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html